# Code Blocks doesn't start in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

After upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, when I open CodeBlocks appears this window. [Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z4so.png)
When I choose GNU GCC Compiler and set it as default and press ok, CodeBlocks throws me out and close the window. I have installed gcc-7,gcc-8,gcc-9. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you launch codeblocks from the terminal, does it give output?

Comment: This is the error from terminal -> (codeblocks:13274): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:59:02.021: gtk_tree_model_iter_nth_child: assertion 'n >= 0' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I'll tap out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346829/8505596), got nothing on that one sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to run Codeblocks as root? I've got same issue but if I run codeblocks as root it works

Comment: If I run program as normal user this window [this window appears](https://imgur.com/mzBcSjz) and then it immediately closes.

Comment: Thank you ms1310 with roots works fine.